# "RxJS could not find any global context"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, rxjs5

My Angular 4 application build via Angular CLI stopped working, apparently out of the blue:

```
ng --version`
```

results in the following error:

```
RxJS could not find any global context (window, self, global)
Error: RxJS could not find any global context (window, self, global)
    at /home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js:15:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:2:14)
```

Comment: They mention this is fixed in v5.4.0 - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade RxJS to 5.1.1; in `package.json` remove the caret (`^`):

```
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
```

and then

```
npm install
```

**Update May 10, 2017:**

Last night, the [RxJS project removed the offending 5.3.2 release and released 5.3.3](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/releases) which addresses this problem so, you can now use a [caret dependency](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/), again, e.g.:

```
"rxjs": "^5.1",
```

**Explanation**:

The RxJS project released 5.3.2 on May 2 which has a backwards compatibility issue. This caused any project with a [caret dependency](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/) on RxJS 5 to fail. The offending 5.3.2 RxJS release was removed on May 9 and replaced with a fixed 5.3.3 release so caret dependencies now work, again.

Comment: what does the caret and other symbols  in versioning mean?

Comment: @LLL -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a broken commit by `rxjs`. Version `5.3.2` has been removed. Just update `rxjs` again to the latest version, and you'll be good to go again. Check the [changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)